# How to dynamically change a function based on tab and cell in Google Sheets for drops downs

Tags: google-sheets

So I can create the dynamic drops downs using IF and Query in Google Sheets and this works great on one sheet. However, I need this to work over multiple sheets. Basically I need to be able to have the drop down menu in multiple cells on multiple tabs. This is the function I use to create the drop down menus:

`=IF(Template!H1="6",FILTER(Sheet4!A:A,Sheet4!B:B=Template!G7),Query(Sheet4!A2:C500,"select B where A contains '"&Template!H1&"'"))`

Template is one tab where people will find the drop down menus (from data validation pointing to the Sheet4 tab that holds this formula)

The problem is that the variables with Template in them are fixed to that one tab. I need to be able to have this drop down on multiple tabs.

Is there a way to call the tab you are on dynamically? If I have a Template2 tab I want it to be able to pull the lists from Sheet4 using the same type of filtering I am using for Template.

Comment: Here is a link to the Google Sheet I am working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zq3uly2pNoIIavDNBfLXCY_NsiA1DmCLt3AsecaVEcs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you don't put the name of the sheet, it should take the data from your current sheet

Comment: The formula is on Sheet4 with the data table for the dropdown menu. It has to call the other sheet where the drop down menu exists. How would I not reference the sheet? If I take off the Template! it will look for the H1 on Sheet4 and it need it to be looking a the choice made on Template. Again this works but if I switch to Template2 how do I get the Sheet4 function to work on this new tab?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, why can't you simply do `=IF(H1="6",FILTER(Sheet4!A:A,Sheet4!B:B=G7),Query(Sheet4!A2:C500,"select B where A contains '"&H1&"'"))`?

Comment: The H1 will only look for H1 on Sheet4. This is if you look at the Google Sheet I linked above you will see I have multiple tabs. Sheet4 acts as the data sheet for the drop down menus. The formula is located on that tab so that it creates a dynamic list that is not visible on the main tabs. On Template I use data validation to call the cell that has this formula in it in order to create a dynamic drop down. However if I go to a different cell or different tab the formula will always stay the same. Is there a way to make it change based on where the drop down is located?

Comment: I don't see any dropdown menu in the sheet you linked...

Comment: If you look at the tab Template, you will see cells with the header strand or standard. They are all drop down menus.

Comment: Ah, I can't see the dropdown because of the readonly. Try putting the formula directly in the validation (instead of from a range, select from formula and write the formula here). It should solve your issue.

Comment: I have done that but then it does not become a dropdown list.

Comment: Ahh I see. Sadly, the only way you could do that would be by hiding the formula on the current sheet. You can't have 2 dropdowns from the same validation but not the same range.